# Undo a newline (\n) printed to command line

Tags: c++, c, stdout

```
printf("Error %d\n", 1);
printf("\nStatus: %d%%", 50);
```

prints

```
Error 1

Status: 50%
```

In this set up, is there any chance to insert `Error 2\n` between `Error 1\n` and `\nStatus: 50%`. I understand that `\r` and `\b` can be used to change printed text *in the same* line (e.g., if there is a single `\n` between `Error 1` and `Status: 50%`), but can I change text in a previous line?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround/hint if you won't find anything other: use a library such as NCurses or PDCurses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot.

But you may issue system calls to clear the whole screen instead, like `system("clear")` (OS-dependent).

Or use `ncurses` just as Kos mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

What @Ryan said.

Explanation why: `stdout` is some abstract stream that doesn't have to be the terminal. It may be a file, a pipe, a socket, a printer, a text to speech device or whatever. In many cases there is no sense to what you asked to do. Hence you need some library that works with the terminal specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ANSI Escapesequences to move your "cursor" one line up:

```
void cursorOnLineUp(void) { printf("\033[1A"); }
```

Or set it to a specific position:

```
void setCursor(int column, int row) { printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, column) }
```

Haven't tried it for C++, but succesfully used it for a simple game in ANSI-C!

Comment: I suppose some terminals don't support it? Like Windows…

Comment: Yup, there's a list of those e.g. [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm), but they only work for VT100-compatible terminals (so wouldn't work under Windows as Ryan said).

Comment: Windows has support for these when ANSI.SYS is running, but it's still going to make a mess if the output is redirected.