# fputs() to same console line after fgets()

Tags: c, newline, stdout, stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char line[100];

    fputs("Enter text: ", stdout);
    fgets(line, 100, stdin);
    putchar('\b');    //doesn't do anything
    fputs("   <-- What a great text!", stdout);
}
```

The code prints:

```
Enter text: (whatever)
   <-- What a great text!
```

Instead, I had hoped for:

```
Enter text: (whatever)   <-- What a great text!
```

So apparently `'\b'` can't backspace the `'\n'` from `stdin`, even if it's the last character.

Any ideas perhaps? C++ would be fine, libraries like `ncurses` not. FYI: [A similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4531000/385513) dealing with `stdout` no user input only.

Comment: how can a backspace on `stdout` affect the `stdin`?

Comment: You have not output **line** you need to add code such as **puts(line);**.

Comment: You have listed your own duplicate. The answer provided there applies. **You can't.**

Comment: If code uses re-directed input `foo < input.txt`, it _should_ backspace, but then your input is missing. (unless you echo it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make use of [console codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[100];
    size_t size;

    size = (size_t)printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(line, 100, stdin);
    printf("\033[A\033[%zuC", size + strlen(line));
    fputs("   <-- What a great text!", stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising; doesn't work on Windows but maybe I can figure that out

Comment: No, it doesn't work on Windows, is Putty an option?

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor forward by N columns(depending on what you are printing) and then move the cursor up by 1 line. For Ex: I'm moving the cursor right by 30 columns and then up by 1 line. This should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char line[100];

    fputs("Enter text: ", stdout);
    fgets(line, 100, stdin);
    printf(" \033[30C");
    printf("\033[1A");
    fputs("   <-- What a great text!", stdout);
}
```

The code prints:

```
Enter text: (whatever)            <-- What a great text!
```